# How to add a background behind an transparent image?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, image

So I have an image of the earth and everything else is transparent. I created it in blender and use a composite setup, to make the atmo slighty blurry(so it doesn't seem like it is has a sharp edge). The issue is that it removes the transparent background and makes it entirely black. When I use an alpha over node at the end to add a space background, then it doesn't work. It only works, when I remove the first alpha over node, that I use for the blurry atmo. [image]

This is my current setup.This is the [blender file](https://file.io/YEyxztdPJzVO)

I hope you can help me fix this. Or maybe a workaround for my "easy" atmospheric blur.

Answer (score 1):

I solved! I inverted the alpha channel to use it as a mask for the background. The black area is the earth, where it darkens completly. With an add and multiply node, I finally managed to add the background!
[image]